Good way to document discouraging the use of a member, type, or pattern that cannot easily be removed?
There is an attribute ObsoleteAttribute that can be used to indicate that a type or member will be removed in a future update and should not be used. I'm working with a large codebase that utilizes some outdated patterns and conventions and I want to hint that its use should be discouraged for future code, at least until we can get a chance to clean things up for the entire codebase (which is unlikely).
e.g.,
public class SomeWidelyUsedClass
{
    // examples of the old approach
    public int? SomeIntA { get; set; }
    public int? SomeIntAId { get; set; }
    public string SomeIntADisplayName { get; set; }

    public int? AnotherIntB { get; set; }
    public int? AnotherIntBId { get; set; }
    public string AnotherIntBDisplayName { get; set; }

    public DateTime? SomeDateC { get; set; }
    public int? SomeDateCId { get; set; }
    public string SomeDateCDisplayName { get; set; }

    // the newer approach, utilizing objects to contain related data
    public FieldInfo<int?> NewIntD { get; set; }
    public FieldInfo<DateTime?> NewDateE { get; set; }
}

I will try to follow the pattern of the established code, despite my own personal tastes when making changes except for really egregious patterns. Then try to follow that pattern for new code where appropriate. But we want to go with the new approach so I want to let others know that this is the direction we should go.
Does there exist an attribute that indicates that a type or member's use should be discouraged in favor of another approach? Something like a "DiscouragedAttribute" or a "DoNotUseThisPatternAttribute." How do we document that entire patterns should be phased out for something else?
Using ObsoleteAttribute in this case doesn't feel right to me as it targets specific members, and indicates it will be removed in the near future. I want to discourage an entire pattern. I also considered using XXX comments to explain why these should not be used but I don't think it is effective for spreading the word as it's not highlighted by the IDE as something that should be considered. Same for XML docs.
For now, I'm applying ObsoleteAttribute to extension methods that have been added to try to simplify accessing/mapping to these members to discourage it but I'd hope there's a better approach. But there are already at least 5 different variations of these methods already and I don't want it to get out of hand.
// I added this previously to replace some really ugly mapping code
[Obsolete("Consider using FieldInfo<T> type for newly mapped fields")]
public static int? GetIntValue(this IDataRepository data, string name, out int? id, out string displayName);


What happened to just regular old communication?

Doesn't look like you have much choice, as there isn't anyway to create a custom "obsolete" attribute, at least according to Jon Skeet: c-sharp-custom-obsolete-attribute. Apparently the ObsoleteAttribute is hard coded into the compiler.

I don't know the size of your company or team, but we would discuss this in a meeting, document the decision and create "tech debt" pbis when we come across the old pattern,  maybe mark the existence of the pbi in code so it doesn't get duped ... (by putting the pbi number in a comment)

We also would remind and urge one another to use the new pattern in code reviews.

It sure sounds like what you're describing is that these properties are obsolete.  That you personally seem to think everything that's obsolete will be removed soon is most certainly not a property of something that's obsolete, or are they documented as claiming that.  .NET itself have obsolete things that have been there for 15 years, and with no plan to remove them, ever.

Significant effort: for the pattern in the example, I am quite confident you could write an Analyzer, maybe even with Auto-Fix.

@Servy: That's what I thought too, but, after re-reading it, this is not what OP meant: These properties are not obsolete. NewSomeInt is not a replacement for SomeInt, it's a different property for storing some unrelated data. Calling it SomeOtherInt instead would have made this clearer.

OP: I think there's not much more you can do. Anyone adding a new property will most likely add it at the bottom, and, thus, see (and copy) the new pattern you used rather than the old pattern.

Not sure if this is an actual issue as you are doing everything in your power with [Obsolete].  Rider will cross these functions out, but if you separate out your projects and just import them as a set of DLLs.  [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)] depending on the editor will remove them from Intellisense.

Yes, Heinzi got it. Newly created properties are meant to be the new norm. I can't replace the old way without making drastic changes in our backend APIs as well as our frontend UIs to change them all, hence the question. I am but a member of one of five teams working on this codebase so getting the word out isn't the easiest, especially when new teammates are being rolled in regularly. This was the first time in the couple of years I've been working with them where this came up.

@mxmissile That's a given of course. I'm looking for the case when new members join in and didn't get that initial message or wasn't paying attention to it, and needed an extra poke to know it's not the way.
